# erro na hora de importar .ODS no R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Estou tentando importar uma tabela .ods no R

```
library(readODS)
setwd("~/Documents/Mestrado/dissertacao")
dados <- read_ods("teste.ods", col_names = T)
```

contudo quando carrega a planilha ele não identifica a primeira linha como nome das colunas e carrega os dados como caracter.
Já tentei converter para matriz e para data frame mas continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: anexe na pergunta o arquivo "teste.ods"

Answer (score 1):

Para ler arquivos ".ods" basta usar a função `read_ods` do pacote `readODS`.

No exemplo abaixo eu crio um arquivo ODS com os dados do [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) `mtcars` e depois o leio.

```r
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".ods")
readODS::write_ods(mtcars, tf)

mtcars2 <- readODS::read_ods(tf)
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   mpg = col_double(),
#>   cyl = col_double(),
#>   disp = col_double(),
#>   hp = col_double(),
#>   drat = col_double(),
#>   wt = col_double(),
#>   qsec = col_double(),
#>   vs = col_double(),
#>   am = col_double(),
#>   gear = col_double(),
#>   carb = col_double()
#> )
```

Veja que a informação lida é idêntica a informação salva.

```
head(mtcars2)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Vale a pena notar que o argumento `col_names = TRUE` é o argumento padrão e, portanto, não precisa ser fornecido.